# Android: cannot switch to new activity on click

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a homepage with two buttons.  Button1 loads Activity2.class (which displays a map) and Button2 loads Login.class (which displays a login form).

Button1 is working, but Button2 does nothing when clicked.  I just can't see the difference, I'm using the exact same code structure for both buttons.  Maybe I've missed something in a different file?

This android stuff is all new to me, hope someone can help!

Here's my code (there are no errors)

Main activity.

```
public class AppActivity extends Activity {

Button button;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    addListenerOnButton();
}

public void addListenerOnButton() {

    final Context context = this;

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, App2Activity.class);
            startActivity(intent);   

        }

    });



}

public void addListenerOnButton2() {

    final Context context = this;

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, Login.class);
            startActivity(intent);   

        }

    });

}
}
```

Here's the Login activiy I'm trying to get to

```
public class Login extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // setting default screen to login.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.login);

    }
}
```

Login.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:fillViewport="true">
  <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="#ffffff">

    <LinearLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:padding="10dip">

      <!--  Email Label -->
      <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#372c24"
            android:text="Student Number"/>
      <EditText android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
            android:singleLine="true"/>
      <!--  Password Label -->
      <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#372c24"
            android:text="Password"/>
      <EditText android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:password="true"/>
      <!-- Login button -->
      <Button android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:text="Login"/>
    <!-- Login Form Ends -->
    </LinearLayout>

  </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.mkyong.android"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".AppActivity" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".App2Activity" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".Login" >           
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: addListenerOnButton2() add this in onCreate method

Comment: you are calling App2Activity not Login ???

Answer (score 3):

You're not calling `addListenerOnButton2();`

Comment: Thanks a lot guys!  Knew it was something trivial!

Answer (score 0):

On the on createMethod of AppActivity class add `addListenerOnButton2(`) just like u add
`addListenerOnButton()`;

```
public class AppActivity extends Activity
{

Button button;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    addListenerOnButton();
    addListenerOnButton2();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Missing method call addListenerOnButton2()

Answer (score 0):

Change your block of code to the following

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
addListenerOnButton();
addListenerOnButton2();// you are not calling this method in your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You never make a call to the addListenerOnButton2() method in your onCreate() (or anywhere else in the code you've posted).

Answer (score 0):

Try this Below code.

```
 public class AppActivity extends Activity {

    Button button,button1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

                button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
            button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

            button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(AppActivity.this, App2Activity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);   

                }

            });

            button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(AppActivity.this, Login.class);
                    startActivity(intent);   

                }

            });
 }
```